# Tapping Hybrid meters

Tags: time-signatures

Let's say I have the hybrid time signature given by 5/4 = 3/4 + 2/4.

Would I tap this as 5 evenly spaced pulses?

or is it two evenly spaced beats divided respectively into 3 and 2 evenly spaced pulses, the result being 5 *unevenly* spaced pulses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between 5/4 and 3/4+2/4 is not in the timing, it’s in the inherent stress or emphasis.

If we think of size indicating stress, like strong=**O**, medium=0 and weak=o then we can map out how some popular beats are normally stressed:

- 4/4 = **O** o 0 o | **O** o 0 o |
- 2/4 = **O** 0| **O** 0 |
- 3/4 = **O** 0 o | **O** 0 o | **OR**  **O** o o | **O** o o |
- 5/4 =  **O** o 0 o o| **O** o 0 o o| **OR** maybe  **O** o 0 o 0|**O** o 0 o 0|

So we can see how 3/4 + 2/4 is different from 5/4:

- 3/4+2/4 =  **O** o o  **O** 0 | **O** o o  **O** 0 |

**The timing is the same**, it’s just the pattern of emphasis that is different. So to actually answer: five *evenly spaced* pulses.

See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_signature#Additive_meters

Comment: Never seen or played 5/4 as **O**oOoO, with emphasis on the last beat. Often seen and played as **O**ooOo though.

Comment: And 3/4+2/4 is more like **O**oo**O**o, coming in, simplified, as 5/4, with, as you say, each beat the same duration.

Comment: @Tim I’ve always felt that a march has a slightly stronger second best than the second beat of 4/4, but to me **O** 0 and **O** o are virtually the same. Regarding a slightly stronger fifth beat in 5/4, I was kinda thinking of “My Wave” by Soundgarden. It just doesn’t feel like that last beat is weak. But again, small quibble, IMHO in the face of understanding what meter is meant to convey.

Comment: It's not criticism, more a generalisation of what I've come across. Yes, a march in 2/4 will have a stronger than normal beat 2, rather like a march in 6/8, with that emphasis on 'beat4'. I guess the archetypical 5/4 is going to be 'Take Five' which *is* 3+2, which maybe the OP should listen to, to understand an answer.    Possibly 'My Wave' has that beat 5 emphasis to help keep time due to sliding between 5/4 and 4/4 - just a thought...